# I cannot print the final value of a variable

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm new in Python and I'm trying the write to final value of `recAdd` on my fibonacci recursive version.  Here is my code:

```
recAdd=0
def fibonacciRecursive(n):
    global recAdd
    if n==1 or n==0:        
        return n
    else:
        recAdd=recAdd+1
        return fibonacciRecursive(n-1)+fibonacciRecursive(n-2)
    print(recAdd)
```

After I called my function, it returns only fibonacci value and not `recAdd`.I want to print both of them.  What should I do to print the `recAdd` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dedent the `print` and place it after you call the function

```
def fibonacciRecursive(n):
    global recAdd
    if n == 1 or n == 0:        
        return n  # <-- should this be return 1?
    else:
        recAdd = recAdd + 1
        return fibonacciRecursive(n - 1) + fibonacciRecursive(n - 2)

recAdd = 0
fibonacciRecursive(5)
print(recAdd)
```

You could encapsulate this in a wrapper

```
def fib_aux(n):
    global recAdd
    recAdd = 0
    fibonacciRecursive(5)
    print(recAdd)
```

Then just call

```
fib_aux(5)
```

---

Burying the logic in the function is awkward. Here is one way

```
def fibonacciRecursive(n, print_recAdd=True):
    global recAdd
    if n == 1 or n == 0:        
        retval = n  # <-- should this be 1?
    else:
        recAdd = recAdd + 1
        retval = fibonacciRecursive(n - 1, False) + fibonacciRecursive(n - 2, False)
    if print_recAdd:
        print recAdd
    return retval
```

Comment: I want this print line as a part of my fibonacci recursive funtion because i'am importing this fibonacciRecursive() funtion from a python module.So this isnt' working.

Comment: Ok, I've given you 3 alternatives

Comment: By the way,how can i return a value like using print.

Comment: @Tartar, you could change the `print` to `return retval, recAdd`