# Keeping count in recursion method?

Tags: python, recursion

I am using Python. I am trying to keep count in a recursive method. I get an error when I use `count+=1`. Why is that? I also get an error when I use `sum=sum+count`. This is the error:

> local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Here is my code:

```
def receiveOnePing(mySocket, ID, timeout, destAddr):
    #receives ping
    timeLeft = timeout
    while 1:
        startedSelect = time.time()
        whatReady = select.select([mySocket], [], [], timeLeft)
        howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
        if whatReady[0] == []: # Timeout
            return "Request timed out."
        timeReceived = time.time()
        recPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)  
        header = recPacket[20:28]
        type, code, checksum, id, sequence= struct.unpack("bbHHh", header)     
        if id ==ID:
            sizeofdouble = struct.calcsize("d")#returns size of structure
            timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recPacket[28 : 28+sizeofdouble])[0]
            print "Type:%d Code:%d Checksum:0x%08x Packet ID:%d Sequence:%d RTT:%d ms % (type, code, checksum, id, sequence, rtt)
            count+=1
        timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
        if timeLeft <= 0:
            return "Request timed out."
        else :
            return "REPLY from %s " % destAddr
```

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: You need `count = 0` obviously. If you don't first assign to `count` then `count = count + 1` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259837/i-cannot-print-the-final-value-of-a-variable/19259914#19259914

Answer (score 2):

You have not yet assigned the name count to an object. You need to assign count before referencing it. Try:

```
count = 0
```

before you try `count += 1`.

Comment: Yes I understand but when i put count=0 outside of the recursion method, it still gives me that error

Comment: and if I put count=0 in the inside of the method, count remains 1

Comment: If your count remains 1, then id may not equal ID.

Answer (score 2):

You did not end the string on the line print "Type.... You need an ending quotation mark on this line.

Answer (score 0):

Add `count=0` before `timeLeft = timeout`